# Construct group $G=Q\ltimes Z_{7}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I read a example. i have problem.

Let $Q=\langle x, y| x^{9}=y^{3}=1, x^{y}=x^{4}\rangle$ and $Z_{7}$ be a group of order $7$.
I know $\Omega_{1}(Q):=\Omega$ is an abelian group of order $9$. Since 
$Q/\Omega$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $Z_{3}$ of order $3$ of the automorphism group $Aut(Z_{7})$. we may form $G=Q\ltimes Z_{7}$.

Do you need $\Omega_{1}$ for construct G ?

$\Omega_{i}=$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by its elements of order dividing $p^{i}$

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $Q$?  As it stands, $Q$ seems to be a cyclic group of order $3$.  Specifically, if we apply three times the fact that $x$ is sent to $x^{-1}$ by conjugation by $y$, we find that $x$ is sent to itself when conjugated by $y^2$ and is sent to $x^{-1}$ when conjugated by $y^3$.  But $y^3=1$, so $x^{-1}=x$. Together with $x^9=1$, this implies $x=1$, so the presentation simplifies to $\langle y\mid y^3=1\rangle$.

Comment: Parden me its mistak. i apologiz. i edit

Comment: I do not understand what you mean when you say "Do you need $\Omega_1$ to construct $G$?". What is going on is that if $\langle a\rangle=Z_7$ then the action of the semidirect product is $a^z=a$ for $z\in\Omega_1$ while $a^z=a^{4}$ for $z\not\in\Omega_1$ (we have $a^4$ because the map $\phi: a\mapsto a^4$ has order three in $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_7)$). However, we do not need to give the action in terms of arbitrary group elements. Rather, we can give it in terms of the generators for $Q$. That is, $a^x=a^{4}$ while $a^y=a$. Does that make sense? And does it answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use $\Omega_1$ this way you will miss some possibilities for $G=Q\ltimes Z_7$. The way you describe gives one of the four possibilities. So if you want to specify that one possibility, then yes, use $\Omega_1$. If you want all possibilities, then no, do not use it.

Since the Sylow 3-subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_7)$ has order 3, you know that $x^3$ acts as the identity on $Z_7$ for all $x \in Q$. Hence you get an action of $Q/\mho(Q)$ where $\mho_1(Q) = \mho(Q) = \langle x^3 : x \in Q \rangle$.  However, $G/\mho(Q) \cong C_3 \times C_3$ has many homomorphisms to $\operatorname{Aut}(Z_7)$.

In particular, there are four distinct semidirect products $G$ (one of them direct). You can specify one of them by requiring that $\Omega(Q)$ is the kernel of $Q \to \operatorname{Aut}(Z_7)$.

$Q$ has 2 $\operatorname{Aut}(Q)$-orbits of subgroups of order 9. One is $\{ \Omega_1(Q) \}$ and the other, $\{ \langle x \rangle, \langle yx \rangle, \langle y^2x \rangle \}$, consists of 3 cyclic subgroups of order 9. The semidirect products with kernel $\Omega_1(Q)$ are all isomorphic, but if the kernel is in the other orbit, then there are two possible actions, $z^y = z^2$ or $z^y = z^4$, giving two more semidirect products. Also the kernel could be order 27, giving the direct product as a fourth possibility.

Comment: The semidirect products with kernel $\Omega_{1}(Q)$ are all isomorphic. ????

Comment: Yes. There are two such semidirect products, $z^x=z^2$ and $z^x=z^4$, but these are isomorphic.